# How to use GstSplitMuxSink in C?

Tags: gstreamer

I try to use "format-location" signal of GstSplitMuxSink:

```
g_signal_connect(splitmuxsink, "format-location",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_format_location), NULL);
...

gchar* on_format_location(GstSplitMuxSink *splitmux, guint fragment_id,
            gpointer user_data);
```

But see that:

```
error: unknown type name ‘GstSplitMuxSink’
```

I include gst/gst.h in .c file, but this is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution from gstreamer-devel

> The plugin headers are not public. You can't include them. Just use
>   GstElement * splitmux instead. Also see
>
> $ gst-inspect-1.0 splitmuxsink
>     ... Element Signals:
>
> "format-location" :  gchararray user_function (GstElement* object,
>                                                    guint arg0,
>                                                    gpointer user_data);